# jQuery multiple filters on selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to select last div which id starts with "level":

```
var div = $('div[id^="level"]:last');
```

But as well I'd like to select the last and visible one. How could I perform that? Following doesn't work:

```
$('div[id^="level"]:last:visible');
```

I tried couple different combinations but none worked.

Comment: Try switching your `:last` and `:visible`

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Seems very obvious today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching your `:last` and `:visible` that was you first filter all the elements by their visibility, and *then* filter for the last one.

```
$('div[id^="level"]:visible:last');
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
var div = $('div[id^="level"]:last').filter(":visible");
```

Comment: That would work as well, but witch switched `:last` and `:visible`